# GCP Firestore export shows IDs instead of names

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, export

I'm trying to export a single collection from the Google Cloud Platform Console but for one of my projects (Firebase project was created around 2020) it shows IDs instead of the collection names.

The URL to the page I'm referring to: https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/export?authuser=0&hl=de&project=wb-rro-staging

Newer project:
[image]

Older project:
[image]

How can I fix the older project so it shows me the collection names instead of unusable IDs? Is this possible without having to create an entirely new Firebase project and migrating EVERYTHING over there?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Was this project created with these IDs originally or it is the export display you can see these.Also check this related document for [Data Import and Export from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)

Comment: @Vaidehi Jamankar thanks for your reply. The project was created by someone else in 2020 but the collections always had human readable names/IDs. Maybe Firestore worked differently back then as the collection names of the new project are correct. Hopefully there is no need to migrate everything just for this to work.